# Parse array with non named values with Gson/Retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have a response from server with an array that contains from values without names, just values like `[tag:tag, tag:tag]`

Here is the working example:

```
 "result": {
        "vendors": {
            "type": "growing",
            "queryString": "fruits[]",
            "values": {
                "1": "Apple",
                "2": "Pear",
                "3": "Mango",
                "4": "Pineapple",
.....
```

How can I parse this answer to POJO? I understand it's easy with wrapping array into {id:1, name:apple}, but how I can manage with this without it?

Comment: 1,2,3 and 4 are Json Objects... sadly that json has not the best format. You should contact the WS API dev to make it more "parse" friendly. If those numbers are objects with not a useful meaning, the WS API dev  should go for an Array of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

1) if you can get the server to change that serialization format, get them to do it.  It is sketchy.

2) if you cannot change the server format, you can implement a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html). Here is a custom adapter that just reads in values, discarding the name/index, and adds to the list.

```
public class VerboseArrayTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, List<String> value) throws IOException {
        // Hopefully you don't need to serialize in this format, too!
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.peek() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            in.nextName();
            elements.add(in.nextString());
        }
        in.endObject();
        return elements;
    }
}
```

Annotate your vendor class as below (note, I am not showing the wrapping classes you have) --

```
public class Vendors {
    String type;
    String queryString;
    @JsonAdapter(VerboseArrayTypeAdapter.class)
    List<String> values;
}
```

**NOTE** A couple of caveats here -- we ignore the index's in the JSON.  So either a) you need to be sure the server always serializes the elements in order, or b) you don't care about the order.

3) see point 1.